# EXTJS grid within a Facebook application that uses FBML

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, extjs

Greetings. I'm trying to add an EXTJS grid to my facebook application. The facebook application was configured to use FBML.

The EXTJS javascript works perfect when I run it from my apache server but when I add the same code to the my facebook application the grid does not render. The renderTo is set to the following:

```
renderTo: document.body
```

When I do a view source I see my EXTJS code but again it does not render. Is this possible or do I need to switch my facebook app to be iframe based?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to switch from FBML to iFrame(and use xFBML with the FBJS API)
Then, it should work :)
As far as i know, in FBML application there is no body tag.
I think FBML is to be deprecated from Facebook.